# How to prove Ross《stochastic Process》(Second Edition)packing problem clearly？

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In ROSS book《Stochastic Process》page29

there is Example1.5（f）

I want to know why it's rigorous

**Pi,n=Pi · P(n-i+1)**

the author think the line with n points can be separated as two lines with i

and n-i+1 points.then

**Pi,n=Pi · P(n-i+1)**

**Pi,n stands for the ith point is "isolated point" on the"n points line"
Pi stands for the ith point is "isolated point" on the"i points line"**

**P(n-i+1) stands for the (n-i+1)th point is "isolated point" on the"(n-i+1) 
points line"**

However,I think

the probability of"point pairs" selected on the "n points line"

is different with that

when selected on "i point line" and"n-i+1 point line". 
**because Pi is related to the random selection probability 1/(i-1),which not exist in the problem**

So why "**Pi,n=Pi · P(n-i+1)**"is right?

MANY THANKS!

I'am a student from peking University of China,thanks again.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PNWg.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbfGA.png)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tytoz.png)
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvlb8.png)
[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgGw6.png)
[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwPqh.png)
[7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuUqY.png)
[8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JsMY.png)

Comment: picture 1~8 are all about this examples answer ,I can't understand the equation mentioned above,please help,thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).